# How to render excel file from dynamic result set in Play framework for download without using server memory

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3, playframework-2.5

I am new to play framework. I have a scenario where the play application should retrieve the result set from a data-warehouse and return it to the client. I have a working code which uses ByteArrayOutputStream and 
Chunked transfer encoding to accomplish the task. It is given below,

```
val responseStream: java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()


val sheetOne = Workbook {

   ...

}

val workbookImpure = new WorkbookImpure(sheetOne)
workbookImpure.saveToStream(responseStream)



Ok.chunked(
   Enumerator(responseStream.toByteArray).andThen(Enumerator.eof)
).as("application/vnd.ms-excel").withHeaders("Content-Disposition" -> s"attachment; filename=*filename*.xls")
```

I construct the excel workbook from result set and use ByteArrayOutputStream to write it as a file.But the problem is that the ByteArrayOutputStream uses memory.

I would like to know if there is a way in play framework to render files for download (using Ok.chunked()) without using memory.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Technically everything uses memory but some solutions use less than others. So you should try to use Akka Streams, this will allow you to pass bytes directly to the client without building whole file in memory.